# $\int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin t dt =\int_{\pi/2}^\pi f(t)\sin t dt < f(\frac{\pi}{2}) \Rightarrow \int_0^\pi \sqrt{f(t)} dt < \pi \sqrt{f(\frac{\pi}{2})}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, integral-inequality

Assume $f:[0,\pi]\rightarrow (0,+\infty)$ is continuous. And
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin t dt =\int_{\pi/2}^\pi f(t)\sin t dt
\tag{1}
$$
if
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin t dt < f(\frac{\pi}{2})
\tag{2}
$$
then, how to show
$$
\int_0^\pi \sqrt{f(t)} dt < \pi \sqrt{f(\frac{\pi}{2})}    ~~~~~~?
\tag{3}
$$

I guess it when I read some paper. I am not sure it is right. And I don't know how to prove it. Seemly, the Holder, Cauchy, Young inequalities are useless for it.

**Response to mathworker21 (2023-8-25):** I calculated a function liking $\delta^{-2}1_{[0,\delta]}+1_{[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2})}+c1_{\{\frac{\pi}{2}\}}$. For convenience, let
$$
f(t)=\delta^{-2}1_{[0,\delta]}+1_{[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon)}+
k(t-\frac{\pi}{2}+\epsilon) 1_{[\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon,  \frac{\pi}{2}]}
$$
First, I have
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin tdt =
-\delta^{-2}\cos\delta+\delta^{-2}-\sin\epsilon+\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}+k-k\cos\epsilon   \\
f(\frac{\pi}{2}) = k\epsilon
$$
So, $\int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin(t)dt < f(\frac{\pi}{2})$ imply
$$
k< \frac{
\delta^{-2}\cos\delta  - \delta^{-2}  +\sin\epsilon  -\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}
}
{
1-\epsilon-\cos\epsilon
}
\tag{5}
$$
On the other hand, we have
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{f(t)}dt =
1+\frac{\pi}{4}-\epsilon+\frac{2}{3k}(k\epsilon)^{3/2}
$$
Therefore, $\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{f(t)}dt=\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{f(\frac{\pi}{2})}$ imply
$$
\sqrt k = \frac{
1+\frac{\pi}{4}-\epsilon
}{
\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt\epsilon -\frac{2}{3}\epsilon^{3/2}
}
\tag{6}
$$
However, It is not possible to satisfy both conditions (5) and (6) simultaneously. I use Wolfram Mathematica (a software) to get that when $\epsilon=10^{-10},\delta=10^{-10}$, (5)  imply
$$
k<1.207106781146902863457773*10^{10}
$$
(6) imply
$$
k=1.291904506901873765116087*10^{10}
$$
Of course, I also test other numerical value. For example, $\epsilon=10^{-6},\delta=10^{-6}$ or $\epsilon=10^{-10},\delta=10^{-6}$  and so on. But (5) and (6) can't be satisfied simultaneously.

Besides, I also calculated
$$
f(t)=\delta^{-2}1_{[0,\delta]}+1_{[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon)}+
k^2(t-\frac{\pi}{2}+\epsilon)^2 1_{[\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon,  \frac{\pi}{2}]}
$$
It also is not the counterexample of statement 2.

> The Mathematica code:
> [image]
> [image]

**Response to mathworker21 (2023-8-22):** I find that
$$
f(t) = \delta^{-2}1_{[0,\delta]}(t)+1_{[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}]}(t)
$$
is not the  counterexample  of

Statement $2$: For every continuous $f : [0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \to (0,+\infty)$ satisfying $\int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin(t)dt < f(\frac{\pi}{2})$, we have $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{f(t)}dt < \frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{f(\frac{\pi}{2})}$.

For this $f(t)$ there always be $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{f(t)}dt < \frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{f(\frac{\pi}{2})}$. However,
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin(t)dt 
=-\delta^{-2}\cos\delta +\delta^{-2}+\cos\frac{\pi}{4}
~~~~~~~
f(\frac{\pi}{2})=1
$$
for any $\delta\in (0,\frac{\pi}{4})$,  there is
$$
-\delta^{-2}\cos\delta +\delta^{-2}+\cos\frac{\pi}{4} >1
$$

> [image]

**Response to mathworker21 (2023-8-11):** Could you explain why it is equivalent to showing
$$
\left(\frac{1}{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{f(t)}dt\right)^2 \le \int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin(t)dt  
~~?
\tag{4}
$$
In fact, I also don't understand Ryszard Szwarc's comment.

Besides, I calculate your example, when $\delta>0$ is sufficiently small, it is not false. For
$$
f(t) = \delta^{-1/2}1_{[0,\delta]}(t)+1_{[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}]}(t)
$$
I have
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{f(t)}dt=
\int_0^\delta \sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt\delta}}dt
+
\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} dt
=\delta^{3/4}+\frac{\pi}{4}
$$
Therefore, the left part of (4) is
$$
L=\frac{4}{\pi^2} \delta^{3/2} +\frac{2}{\pi}\delta^{3/4}+\frac{1}{4}
$$
On the other hand, the right part of (4)  is
$$
R=
\int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin t dt
=
\int_0^\delta \frac{1}{\sqrt\delta} \sin t dt 
+
\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \sin t dt
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt\delta}-\frac{1}{\sqrt\delta}\cos\delta+\cos\frac{\pi}{4}
$$
And
$$
\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0^+} L =\frac{1}{4}
~~~~~~
\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0^+} R =\cos\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}
$$
So, when $\delta>0$ is sufficiently small, there is $L\le R$.

But, I use Mathematica to get the grapha of $L-R$, there is $L>R$ when $\delta$ near $\pi/4$.

> **$x$ is the $\delta$**
> [image]

**PS(2023-8-8):** From two aspects, I think it is right. First, by the rearrangement inequality, I feel it is right. But it is not general rearrangement, the maximum value of $f$ should be placed near $\frac{\pi}{2}$ in the rearrangement. But I still can't give a detailed proof up to now.

On the other hand, I write a program to verify it. I approximate the integral by summation. There is not counter-example. The Python code is as follows:

```
import math
import random

i=0
while i<10000:
    i=i+1

    #生成一个随机函数  (Generates a random function)
    f_list=[]
    for i0 in range(0,200):
        f_list.append(random.random())

    #计算左边积分  (Compute the left-hand integral of (1) )
    L=0
    for i1 in range(0,100):
        L=L+f_list[i1]*math.sin(i1*math.pi/200)*(math.pi/200)

    #计算右边积分  (Compute the right-hand integral of (1) )
    R=0
    for i2 in range(100,200):
        R=R+f_list[i2]*math.sin(i2*math.pi/200)*(math.pi/200)

    #调整两边积分的大小  (Adjust the size of the integral on both sides of (1) )
    d=L/R
    for i3 in range(100,200):
        f_list[i3]=f_list[i3]*d

    #判断是否小于f(pi/2)  (Determine if it is less than f(pi/2))
    if L>= f_list[100]:
        i=i-1
        continue   #跳过循环剩下部分  (Skip the rest of the loop)

    #计算最后一个式子中左边的积分  (Calculate the integral on the left of the (3) )
    LL=0
    for i4 in range(0,200):
        LL=LL+math.sqrt(f_list[i4])*(math.pi/200)

    #如果是反例，就打印出来  (If it's a counterexample, print it out)
    if LL >= math.pi*math.sqrt(f_list[100]):
        print(LL,math.pi*math.sqrt(f_list[100]),LL-f_list[100])

print("End")
```

Comment: Where does this come from? Why do you think that the inequality holds?

Comment: @MartinR  I just thought of it, not where  I saw it. At beginning, I just feel it maybe right. I don't know how to explain this feeling.  Later, I feel it can be proved by some special rearrangement.  Besides, I write a program to verify it.  I have add the detail in problem. Thanks.

Comment: It suffices to show that $$\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{f(t)}\,dt<{\pi\over 2}\sqrt{f(\pi/2)}$$  Both inequalities are satisfied if the maximal value is attained at $\pi/2,$ and the function is not constant on the interval $[0,\pi/2].$ So potential counterexample should attain the maximal value somewhere in $(0,\pi/2).$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc  I don't know why it  suffices to show $\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{f(t)}\,dt<{\pi\over 2}\sqrt{f(\pi/2)}$. Could you explain it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is equivalent to showing
$$\left(\frac{1}{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{f(t)}dt\right)^2 \le \int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin(t)dt$$
for any measurable $f : [0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \to (0,+\infty)$.

But this is of course false. For example, one can take $$f(t) = \delta^{-2}1_{[0,\delta]}(t)+1_{[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}]}(t)$$ for a sufficiently small $\delta > 0$ (probably $\delta := 10^{-100}$ suffices).

If you want a concrete counterexample to your original problem, define $f(t)$ on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ as follows and then define $f(t) := f(\pi - t)$ for $t \in [\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$: for $0 \le t \le \delta$, let $f(t) = \delta^{-2}$, then drop $f$ linearly from $\delta^{-2}$ to $0$ over $\delta \le t \le \delta+\delta^{10}$, then keep $f$ at $0$ for $\delta+\delta^{10} \le t \le \frac{\pi}{4}-\delta^{10}$, then increase $f$ linearly from $0$ to $1$ over $\frac{\pi}{4}-\delta^{10} \le t \le \frac{\pi}{4}$, then keep $f$ at $1$ for $\frac{\pi}{4} \le t \le \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Of course, there could be a cleaner counterexample.

---

I now show the equivalence.

Statement $1$: For every continuous $f : [0,\pi] \to (0,+\infty)$ satisfying $\int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin(t)dt = \int_{\pi/2}^\pi f(t)\sin(t)dt$ and $\int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin(t)dt < f(\frac{\pi}{2})$, we have $\int_0^\pi \sqrt{f(t)}dt < \pi \sqrt{f(\frac{\pi}{2})}$.

Statement $2$: For every continuous $f : [0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \to (0,+\infty)$ satisfying $\int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin(t)dt < f(\frac{\pi}{2})$, we have $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{f(t)}dt < \frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{f(\frac{\pi}{2})}$.

Claim: Statement $1$ is equivalent to Statement $2$.

Proof:

> Let's first show Statement $2$ implies Statement $1$.
>
> We are given a continuous $f : [0,\pi] \to (0,+\infty)$ satisfying $\int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin(t)dt = \int_{\pi/2}^\pi f(t)\sin(t)dt$ and $\int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin(t)dt < f(\frac{\pi}{2})$. By the second condition, we have $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{f(t)}dt < \frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{f(\frac{\pi}{2})}$. Letting $g(t) = f(\pi-t)$ for $0 \le t \le \frac{\pi}{2}$, we have that $g: [0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \to (0,+\infty)$ is a continuous function satisfying (by the first condition and that $g(\frac{\pi}{2}) = f(\frac{\pi}{2})$) the inequality $\int_0^{\pi/2} g(t)\sin(t)dt < g(\frac{\pi}{2})$. Therefore, by Statement $2$ applied to $g$, we have $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{g(t)}dt < \frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{g(\frac{\pi}{2})}$, which is equivalent to $\int_{\pi/2}^\pi \sqrt{f(t)}dt < \frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{f(\frac{\pi}{2})}$. Adding the two inequalities we've obtained gives $\int_0^\pi \sqrt{f(t)}dt < \pi\sqrt{f(\frac{\pi}{2})}$.
>
> Let's now show Statement $1$ implies Statement $2$.
>
> We are given a continuous $f : [0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \to (0,+\infty)$ satisfying $\int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin(t)dt < f(\frac{\pi}{2})$. Extend $f$ to $[0,\pi]$ by definition $f(t) := f(\pi-t)$ for $\frac{\pi}{2} \le t \le \pi$. This extended function $f$ is continuous on $[0,\pi]$, still takes values in $(0,+\infty)$, and satisfies $\int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin(t)dt = \int_{\pi/2}^\pi f(t)\sin(t)dt$ and $\int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin(t)dt < f(\frac{\pi}{2})$. Therefore, by Statement $1$, we obtain $\int_0^\pi \sqrt{f(t)}dt < \pi\sqrt{f(\frac{\pi}{2})}$, but $\int_0^\pi \sqrt{f(t)}dt = 2\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{f(t)}dt$ by the definition of the extended $f$. $\square$

Statement $3$: For every measurable $f : [0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \to (0,+\infty)$, we have $$\left(\frac{1}{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{f(t)}dt\right)^2 \le \int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin(t)dt.$$

Claim: Statement $2$ is equivalent to Statement $3$.

Proof:

> Let's first show Statement $3$ implies Statement $2$.
>
> We are given a continuous function $f : [0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \to (0,+\infty)$ satisfying $\int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin(t)dt < f(\frac{\pi}{2})$. By Statement $3$, we know $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{f(t)}dt \le \frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{\int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin(t) dt}$. By our assumption, we obtain $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{f(t)}dt < \frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{f(\frac{\pi}{2})}$, as desired.
>
> Now let's show Statement $2$ implies Statement $3$. It will be easier to prove the contrapositive, namely that a counterexample to Statement $3$ can produce a counterexample to Statement $2$.
>
> So, we are given a measurable function $f : [0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \to (0,+\infty)$ with $\left(\frac{1}{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{f(t)}dt\right)^2 > \int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin(t)dt$. Take $\epsilon > 0$ so that $\left(\frac{1}{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{f(t)}dt\right)^2 > \epsilon+ \int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin(t)dt$. Since continuous functions are dense in measurable functions, we can take some continuous function $g : [0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \to (0,+\infty)$ so that $\int_0^{\pi/2} |f(t)-g(t)|dt \le \frac{1}{10}\epsilon$. Then this function $g$ satisfies $\left(\frac{1}{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{g(t)}dt\right)^2 > \frac{2}{3}\epsilon+ \int_0^{\pi/2} g(t)\sin(t)dt$.
>
> Finally, by modifying the values of $g$ extremely close to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, let $h : [0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \to (0,+\infty)$ be a continuous function with $h(\frac{\pi}{2}) = \left(\frac{1}{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{h(t)}dt\right)^2$ and $\int_0^{\pi/2} |g(t)-h(t)|dt < \frac{1}{10}\epsilon$. We claim this $h$ serves as a counterexample to Statement $2$. Clearly we don't have (the strict inequality) $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{h(t)}dt < \frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{h(\frac{\pi}{2})}$, so it just suffices to verify $\int_0^{\pi/2} h(t)\sin(t)dt < h(\frac{\pi}{2})$. But this follows from the facts that $\left(\frac{1}{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{h(t)}dt\right)^2 > \frac{1}{3}\epsilon+ \int_0^{\pi/2} h(t)\sin(t)dt > \int_0^{\pi/2} h(t)\sin(t)dt$ and $h(\frac{\pi}{2}) = \left(\frac{1}{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{h(t)}dt\right)^2$. $\square$

Comment: Thanks your answer. But I have some query which is a little  long. Therefore, I  write it in above problem.  Could you help me?  Thanks.

Comment: @lanse7pty It's best to ask a new question. Link this question as context in your new post.

Comment: @lanse7pty I sincerely apologize; it should be $\delta^{-2}$ instead of $\delta^{-1/2}$. I just updated my answer. I'll explain the equivalence later, I need to tend to my mother now.

Comment: Thanks very much. You  solve a problem that had been bothering me for a long time. Although the results were not what I expected, but math is so.  This problem has a equivocal geometric background.  Let me think whether I am wrong or some thing I miss.  Thanks again.

Comment: @lanse7pty No problem, nice question. Let me know if you want me to add the equivalence between Statement $2$ and the statement at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: Yes, I want to know the equivalence between statement 2 and the begin statement.

Comment: Don't hurry.  My time is enough.

Comment: I find your $f(t)$ is not counterexample of statement 2. The detail I have added in above problem. Therefore, your first inequality  is not equivalent to statement 2.  Could you explain it ?  Maybe, I misunderstand you.

Comment: @lanse7pty Statement $2$ is indeed equivalent to Statement $3$, but that doesn't mean that a counterexample to one is a counterexample to the other. I added a proof of the equivalence. The idea behind the equivalence is that for Statement $2$ (and Statement $1$), one should insist $f(\frac{\pi}{2}) = \left(\frac{1}{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{f(t)}dt\right)^2$, since this is the "worst case". If you want the concrete counterexample to Statement $2$, simply change the value at $t=\frac{\pi}{2}$ of the counterexample to Statement $3$, which was

Comment: @lanse7pty $\delta^{-2}1_{[0,\delta]}+1_{[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}]}$, at $t = \frac{\pi}{2}$. So, the counterexample to Statement $2$ would be $\delta^{-2}1_{[0,\delta]}+1_{[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2})}+c1_{\{\frac{\pi}{2}\}}$, where $c$ is chosen so that $f(\frac{\pi}{2}) = \left(\frac{1}{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{f(t)}dt\right)^2$. The only remaining issue is that this $f$ is not continuous. But it can be made continuous without changing the values too much -- just replace each indicator with sharp, nearly vertical lines, like I described in my answer.

Comment: @lanse7pty In any event, I added to my answer the proof of the equivalence between Statement $2$ and Statement $3$.

Comment: Thanks  for your  response. But I still need time to verify it, two or three days.  The existence of $h(t)$ is  not obvious for me.

Comment: @lanse7pty No problem. That $h(t)$ exists indeed requires a bit of thought. The (square) integral $\left(\frac{1}{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{g(t)} dt\right)^2$ has some value, call it $c$, between $0$ and $1$. You can then define $h$ to be $g$ except in a small neighborhood of $\pi/2$, in which you change $g$ to ensure $h(\pi/2) = c$. If you do this in a small enough neighborhood of $\pi/2$, this $h$ will actually suffice for the proof. But changing $h$ did change the (square) integral $\left(\frac{1}{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{h(t)} dt\right)^2$, so it's no longer $c$. But it only changed it

Comment: @lanse7pty a little bit. So, if we did the same thing with some $c'$ close to $c$, the result will have $\left(\frac{1}{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{h(t)} dt\right)^2 = h(\pi/2)$; it's an intermediate value theorem argument.

Comment: I calculate some example liking $\delta^{-2}1_{[0,\delta]}+1_{[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2})}+c1_{\{\frac{\pi}{2}\}}$. But it is not counterexample of Statement 2. The detail is added in above problem. But I still can't find any error in your proof. No offence, seemly, somewhere of your proof is not rigorous.  I will try to make it rigorous. Give me about ten days. Thanks your long-term response.

Comment: Could you give a computable couterexample of Statement 2 at here [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4761424/computable-counterexample-of-an-integral-inequality/4761474#4761474]