# $L^1$ norm and an integral inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, integral-inequality

Assume $f : [0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \to (0,+\infty)$ is continuous, and for $\epsilon>0$ small enough, there is
$$
\left(\frac{1}{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{f(t)}dt\right)^2 > \epsilon+ \int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin(t)dt
$$
Then how to show that for any continuous function $g : [0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \to (0,+\infty)$ satisfy
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} |f(t)-g(t)|dt \le \frac{1}{10}\epsilon
$$
there is
$$
\left(\frac{1}{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{g(t)}dt\right)^2 > \frac{2}{3}\epsilon+ \int_0^{\pi/2} g(t)\sin(t)dt
~~~?
$$

This problem is from [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4745864/int-0-pi-2-ft-sin-t-dt-int-pi-2-pi-ft-sin-t-dt-f-frac-pi2), I feel should use Sobolev embedding, but I fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to make the proof work with $\frac{\epsilon}{10}$, since in my proof, I would need $(a+b)^2\le a^2+b^2$, which is false.
But since you are using density, you can take any small quantity you want.
Fix $0<\varepsilon<\epsilon$ and take $g$ so that
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}|f(t)-g(t)|\,dt\leq\varepsilon
$$
You have
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}g(t)\sin t\,dt  & =\int_{0}^{\pi/2}f(t)\sin t\,dt+\int%
_{0}^{\pi/2}(g(t)-f(t))\sin t\,dt\\
& \leq\int_{0}^{\pi/2}f(t)\sin t\,dt+\int_{0}^{\pi/2}|f(t)-g(t)|\,dt\\
& \leq\int_{0}^{\pi/2}f(t)\sin t\,dt+\varepsilon\leq\int_{0}^{\pi/2}f(t)\sin
t\,dt+\frac{\epsilon}{3}%
\end{align*}
provided $\varepsilon\leq\frac{\epsilon}{3}$. On the other hand, by
Holder's inequality
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{f(t)}\,dt  & =\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{g(t)+(f(t)-g(t))}%
\,dt\\
& \leq\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{g(t)}\,dt+\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{|f(t)-g(t)|}%
\,dt\\
& \leq\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{g(t)}\,dt+(\pi/2)^{1/2}\left(  \int_{0}^{\pi
/2}|f(t)-g(t)|\,dt\right)  ^{1/2}\\
& \leq\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{g(t)}\,dt+(\pi/2)^{1/2}\varepsilon^{1/2}%
\end{align*}
and similarly,
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{g(t)}\,dt\leq\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{f(t)}\,dt+(\pi
/2)^{1/2}\varepsilon^{1/2}%
$$
and so
\begin{align*}
\left(  \frac{1}{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{f(t)}\,dt\right)  ^{2}  &
\leq\left(  \frac{1}{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{g(t)}\,dt+\frac
{\varepsilon^{1/2}}{(\pi/2)^{1/2}}\right)  ^{2}\\
& \leq\left(  \frac{1}{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{g(t)}\,dt\right)
^{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{(\pi/2)}+\frac{2\varepsilon^{1/2}}{\pi/2}\int_{0}%
^{\pi/2}\sqrt{g(t)}\,dt\\
& \leq\left(  \frac{1}{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{g(t)}\,dt\right)
^{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{(\pi/2)}+\frac{2\varepsilon^{1/2}}{\pi/2}\left(
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{f(t)}\,dt+(\pi/2)^{1/2}\right)  \\
& \leq\left(  \frac{1}{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{g(t)}\,dt\right)
^{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}%
\end{align*}
provided $\varepsilon$ is taken small enough.
Now combine these two inequalities.

Comment: Thanks your clear and understandable answer. Very presumptuous to disturb you, could you help me  check the part of Statement 2 implies Statement 3 of [this answer] [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4745864/int-0-pi-2-ft-sin-t-dt-int-pi-2-pi-ft-sin-t-dt-f-frac-pi2/4751154?noredirect=1#comment10097694_4751154]  ?  I am not sure whether it is right. And I verify the author's function, it is not counterexample.

Comment: To make sure it is right, you have to construct the function $h$ as suggested in the messages . It should be $h=g$ in $[0,\pi/2-\delta]$ and $h=a+bx$, where you take $a$ and $b$ so that $g(\pi/2-\delta)=a+b(\pi/2-\delta)$ and $a+b\pi/2=c$. Sorry but I don’t have the time to do all the computations. It seems plausible that $h$ should exist but the only way to know is to do all the computations

Comment: Thanks, I calculated a $h$ as you construct, it is not counterexample.