# Computable counterexample of an integral inequality

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, integral-inequality

Statement 2: For every continuous $f : [0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \to (0,+\infty)$ satisfying $\int_0^{\pi/2} f(t)\sin(t)dt < f(\frac{\pi}{2})$,  then
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{f(t)}dt < \frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{f(\frac{\pi}{2})}
$$

The Statement 2 is from [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4745864/int-0-pi-2-ft-sin-t-dt-int-pi-2-pi-ft-sin-t-dt-f-frac-pi2). The mathworker21 prove it is false by prove it is equivalent  to another statement. I was disturbed by his proof (although I don't find material mistake). Besides, he did not give a direct counterexample.  Therefore, I want an computable counterexample to end my doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is naturally to use a computer to construct a computable counterexample.
First, define a function $f_0$ on $\left[0,\tfrac{\pi}2\right]$ by putting
$$f_0(t)=
\cases{1.124, & when $0\le t<0.2$,\\
0.9, & when $0.2\le t<0.3$,\\
1,& when $0.3\le t<\pi/2$.}
$$
The calculations with Mathcad yield that the function $f_0$ satisfies the required inequalities, that is $$\int_0^{\pi/2} f_0(t)\sin(t)dt=0.9999987... 
<1=f_0\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right),$$
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{f_0(t)}dt =1.5777...>1.5707...=\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{f_0\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}.$$

Now observe that if $f$ is any continuous piecewise linear function from $\left[0,\tfrac{\pi}2\right]$ to $[0.9,1.124]$ which is equals to $f_0$ everywhere but sufficiently small neighborhoods of the points $0.2$ and $0.3$ then $f$ satisfies the required inequalities too.

Comment: If possible, could you talk about how to think it ?